# How to ask for permission to access rooftops in New York City?

Tags: digital, permission

I've been shooting for about a year doing a little bit of everything and I have a real passion for doing architecture and cityscapes in New York City and would like to take advantage of everything it has to offer. I have seen a fair share of cityscapes/rooftopping photos which inspired me in the first place to urban explore and take beautiful city views from the top of skyscrapers.

I was wondering how do you go about asking for legal permission to do so in any building (hotel, office, residential)? I was thinking of emailing the owner of the building (if I can get in touch with them) and write up a formal email about my project and refer to my work; signing a waiver excusing any liability issues. I can also offer my photos as a thank you and as a token of appreciation to them for allowing me the opportunity. Also, I was thinking of just simply asking front desk for a tour or ask out-right to take photos on the roof.

How can I increase the likelihood of someone in the building or the owner to allow me to take photos on the roof?

The reason I ask is because I don't want the same photos everyone else took like tourists in the most popular observation decks but something different where the public can't go and only for exclusive access.

Comment: The number of correct answers will vary as much as the number of owners and managers of buildings from which you wish to shoot.

Comment: If you do discover a magic formula for this, please don't hesitate to answer your own question. ;)

Comment: Probably won't help but another option to consider are drones or helicopter rides, if you can get that.

Comment: Maybe see: the photo.net thread on [How do I ask permission to use a location?](http://photo.net/portraits-and-fashion-photography-forum/00SmeU)

Comment: vtc b/c This is a question about asking for permission to access a property, not photography.

Answer (score 3):

1. Have release forms readily available.
2. Make appointment with speak with property manager.
3. Explain your purpose.
4. Ask for permission.
5. Get papers signed.
6. Go take pictures.

Comment: 7. get pictures on the computer and do post work... ;)